# mongoDB cursor difference between foreach loop and while loop

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I am using mongoDB PHP, when I use find query or aggregation framework, the Result is a cursor, I can iterate over the cursor using foreach loop or while loop. For example I have the following query to execute

```
$result = $collection->find();
```

I am able to iterate over the result using following two methods

```
1- foreach($result as $mongoid => $doc) {
        echo "mongoid is " . $mongoid;
        print_r($doc);
    }

2- while ( $result->hasNext() ) {
       $doc = $result->getNext();  
       $result->next();  
       print_r( $doc );
       echo "find one doc in cursor\n";

   }
```

Which of the above iteration method is best and why?

Answer (score 0):

There's no any significant difference when you use `foreach` or `while` in this case. Read loop performance is the same. Using `foreach` makes your code a bit more readable.
You may check write/read loops performance on [The PHP Benchmark](http://www.phpbench.com/).

Comment: You may be write when We just talk about foreach loop and while loop, but  you have to take this thing under your consideration that, when foreach loop is used no MongoDB Cursor method is used but with the While loop to iterate I have used MongoDB Cursor methods eg:-hasNext() and getNext(). does still the code does not have performance difference or any other difference?

Comment: I'm not sure (you have to benchmark that) but i really think that `foreach` loop from your example should be faster than while loop because it doesn't use cursor methods but only core php methods.